# CSS table cell left border with rowspan

Tags: css, html-table

Using CSS I want to add *internal* vertical borders on an HTML table with collapsing borders. I do not want cell borders to appear on the outside of the table. On the face of it this would be easy: just add a left border on every cell except the first cell in a row.

```css
th:not(:first-child), td:not(:first-child) {
  border-left-style: solid;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't take into account a column that spans two rows:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">foobar</td>
      <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this case, the selector doesn't match the cell for "two" because it is the first `<td>` in the row, even though it is rendered as being in the *second* column due to the `rowspan="2"` above.

Surely I'm not the first person to run into this. What's the latest, best-practices approach for ensuring that a cell gets an internal vertical border even though it participates in columns that include `rowspan`?

Comment: Maybe just `td:not(:first-child), td:not([rowspan])`?

Comment: But the cell that should be styled differently is not the `rowspan` cell or even in the same row, but in the _next_ row. The `rowspan` cell itself is not styled differently. So how would `td:not([rowspan])` help when we don't want to change the style of the `rowspan` cell itself?

Answer (score 2):

Andrei Fedorov's answer works well in most cases, but it using `:first-child`/`:nth-child`/`:last-child` on table cells in tables with rowspans and/or colspans is generally fraught with difficulties, and it is possible to define tables for which it doesn't work. For example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th:not(:first-child),
td:not(:first-child) {
  border-left-style: solid;
}

th[rowspan]:not(:last-child),
td[rowspan]:not(:last-child) {
  border-right-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td rowspan="2">foo<br>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">two<br>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>four</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Fortunately, there is a more table specific way to meet the requirement, by making use of the [border conflict resolution](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#border-conflict-resolution) rules for collapsing borders. The technique is to give all the cells both inline borders, and give the table inline borders a style of "hidden". The table borders collapse with the cell borders and in the collapsing borders rules, the "hidden" style value trumps any other style values, so the outer borders are not shown and only the inner borders remain.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-inline-style: hidden;
}
td, th {
  border-inline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td rowspan="2">foo<br>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">two<br>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>four</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That sounds promising. I don't quite understand it yet, and I note that the specification is still in draft. I had added a bounty to reward Andrei Fedorov so I'll assign it to him, but I'll hold off on marking one as the answer until I have time to understand this more and/or we get more feedback. Thank you for pointing out this new approach.

Comment: @GarretWilson - Fair enough. On the matter of the specification being in draft, I always link to the latest editor's draft as it generally contains the fewest errors. But the border conflict resolution rules haven't changed since the [original CSS 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution) reached Recommendation in 1998.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks for clarifying. I guess I never got into the nitty-gritty of styling internal table borders back then. I'll try to get some time to dig into that.

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th:not(:first-child),
td:not(:first-child) {
  border-left-style: solid;
}

th[rowspan]:not(:last-child),
td[rowspan]:not(:last-child) {
  border-right-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">foobar</td>
      <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Um, if I know the structure of the table in advance, of course I can work around it. Your example using `[rowspan]` is no different than my putting a special `id` attribute on one of the the `td`s. But my goal here is to have a general solution that works if I don't know the structure of the table in advance. For example, your solution wouldn't work if you switched the order of the columns, would it?

Comment: @GarretWilson I tested whatever table structures I could think of. No problem. Try to provide such a table so that my solution breaks. Then we'll figure out how to fix it. The `td[rowspan]` selector is only relevant when you have no other way to select the elements you are interested in. You cannot use `Id`, because There can only be one element with the same `id` per page.

Comment: I may have been mistaken. (Ignore the comment I added and then deleted.) I think I was forgetting that the `td[rowspan]` columns already have `border-left-style`, it will work if multi-row columns are on the right side, too.  But I think you can simplify the selector to `td[rowspan]:not(:last-child)`, no? (Be careful: the short-hand `border-right: none` is [setting a lot of properties to their initial values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#tricky_edge_cases), which you don't want.)

Comment: Andrei the basic concept wound up working like a charm. Thank you for contributing this. Semantically I don't particularly like that this inherently "overwrite" some borders, but with collapsed borders it doesn't make a difference visibly. I'm going to award this answer a bounty to express my appreciation, but please tweak your answer: 1) I think selector like `td[rowspan]:not(:last-child)` will be more efficient; 2) don't use `border-right: none`, which has the side effect of changing other properties; and 3) you need to add `th[rowspan]:not(:last-child)` as well.

Comment: @GarretWilson fix it.

Comment: Looks good, but I think we need to add the same for `th[rowspan]:not(:last-child)`, don't you think?